Book that I read around 1975, where the main character is a retired space pilot hired to steal an object from a lab called Menlo Park
I'm looking for a book that I read around 1975. The main character is a retired space pilot hired to steal an object from a lab called Menlo Park.
The main character lost his hand in an accident and now has a detachable prosthetic, which he sometimes throws as a weapon.

That's handy...

The real Menlo Park in New Jersey or some place named for Edison's lab? (Or the original Menlo Park in California?)

Rogue in Space by Fredric Brown. It is a fixup of two short stories, and was published in 1957.
You have mis-remembered it slightly. The protagonist Crag is not a retired pilot, though he was a pilot before turning to a life of crime:

Call him Crag; it was the name he was using and it will serve as well as any name. He was a smuggler and a thief and a killer. He’d been a spaceman once and had a metal hand to show for it.

Crag is framed for a crime then allowed to escape by the judge, who then pays him a million dollars to steal from a lab called just Menlo, not Menlo Park, though it was named after Edison's workshop.

He already knew, of course, considerable about Eisen. Eisen was a scientist and inventor who, early in his career, must have been struck by the similarities - even the slight similarity of names - between himself and Edison, an inventor of several centuries before, and for that reason had named his workshop Menlo after Edison's Menlo Park.

Crag's left hand is detachable and he uses it as a weapon in the way you describe:

Nor had anyone ever guessed that it was detachable, since all similar artificial hands - or feet or arms or legs - were surgically and permanently attached to their wearers. That was why they had not taken it away from him when he was arrested nor when he had been stripped and given prison garb here at the jail. A renegade surgeon hiding out in Rio had fixed that part of it for him (Crag had fabricated the hand himself) by grafting and manipulating muscle tissue at the stump of the wrist so that holding it on was automatic and involuntary. But by willing the muscles to relax, the heavy hand was instantly detachable, and became a missile that his right hand could throw, after long practice, with deadly accuracy. One might well say that Crag had a long reach, for one blow. And one blow was always sufficient, against a single antagonist.
It was the only weapon Crag ever carried.

